# Django migration not picking up all the model fields

Tags: django, model, migration

I created a new Django project on Windows 10, with the latest python and Django.  After creating the model with a number of tables/models on one model it skipped some fields.  After retrying it would not create a new migration script.  I looked at the initial 0001_initial.py and the fields were missing in that file.    I later added a single new field and that field migrated property but not the missing fields.  All other models were successfully updated in the initial migration.  This happens to be a SQLite DB.

The model that is missing fields:

```
class articles(models.Model):
    """  articles"""
    title = models.CharField (max_length=500)
    teaser = models.CharField (max_length=500)
    summary = models.CharField (max_length=1500)
    byline = models.CharField (max_length=250)
    category = models.SmallIntegerField
    articlenote = models.CharField (max_length=1000)
    author = models.CharField
    publishedDate = models.DateTimeField
    articleStatus = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    articleText = models.TextField
    last_update= models.DateTimeField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The missing fields are :   category, author, publishedDate, articleText

Interesting after trying to rerun the migration I was getting Missing Defaults errors on a new table I was creating.

Since this is a brand new project I can just blow away the database and the migration scripts and try again.  I would like to knwo what is potentially causing this missing migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the initialization of the fields.

So instead of `author = models.CharField`, use `author = models.CharField(max_length=256)` and also for all the others, use the parentheses.

Comment: What I didn't realize is that all fields require the ().  I didn't put them on integers nor text fields which I thought did not need them.

Comment: Without the parentheses, you're defining these variables as a class, but you need to define them as an object of that class.